# Can Cisco Router be used as DNS server?

Tags: router

I know that the latest Cisco Routers can be used as DHCP server. 
I have 2 questions:

1. Can Cisco Routers be used as DNS server too?
2. Can router, that is used as DHCP server, lease ip addresses to specific MAC addresses (as in usual DHCP server)?

Comment: Yes, but you really don't want to use the DNS server in the router, and the DHCP should only be used for small networks. You really want separate servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to configure DNS server on your Cisco router.

The first portion enables the DNS service on the router and enables lookups on the local router.

```
R1# configure terminal
R1(config)# ip dns server
R1(config)# ip domain-lookup
```

The next step is to configure upstream DNS servers for lookups that you do not have entries for. This is optional if you only want to lookup names that you specify and no other.

```
R1(config)# ip name-server 8.8.8.8
R1(config)# ip name-server 4.4.4.4
```

The next step allows you to create manual entries on the router for entries host1, host2 and host3 which will resolve to the IP address at the end,

```
R1(config)# ip host host1 192.168.1.10
R1(config)# ip host host2 192.168.1.11
R1(config)# ip host host3 192.168.1.12
```

When you perform name resolution on the router, you will get the correct IP address that you have added in the previous steps.

Just make sure your other clients use the **routers** IP address to use the DNS service on the router itself.

**DHCP POOL WITH RESERVATIONS**

To answer your DHCP server question. You can use the client identifier to reserve by MAC address.

```
ip dhcp pool MYPOOL
   host 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.0
   client-identifier 0123.1e9e.99de.aa12
   default-router 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: how can we add some hosts (for example 10 hosts) to reserve?

Comment: You should be able to add additional hosts to the MYPOOL and just keep adding client-identifier with MAC address. If you want to use BOOTP then you can add the hardware address rather than client-identifier.

Comment: I tried to launch that command in emulator, it did not recognize my "ip dns server" command. Is this command new? Is this command known only in latest routers?

Comment: if you are using Packet Tracer, this command is not available. Packet Tracer does not support every command that you would see on a physical router. Your other option could be to use GNS3.